# How to program control+C signal in C language to pause and unpause the output?

Tags: c, signals

I am new to programming in C also less knowledge working with control signals. Below is my program in which I am trying to `pause` and `unpause` my output running inside the while loop. So far I am able to `Pause` the output by pressing **CTRL+C** but I am required to `unpause` the output again by pressing **CTRL+C** which I don't know how to do so. My question is how to `Unpause` my output again by pressing **CTRL+C** keys. Also I am using Spinlock to suspend the output until **CTRL+C** is not pressed again which will resume the program to finish displaying output. This program utilizes sleep function to output to the terminal every second. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>

void f(int); //handler

int main( int ac, char* av[] )
{

  if(ac == 1)
  {
    printf("No argument provided");
    exit(1);
  }
  int i = atoi(av[1]);
  printf("This is argument av: %i ", i);
  printf("\n");

  signal( SIGINT, f); // install the handler

  int k = 0;
  while(k != i)
  {
    printf("help \n");
    sleep(1);
    k++;
  }

  return 0;

}

void f(int signum)
{
  while(signum)
  {
    int lock =0;
    if(lock == 1)
      continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: We're not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: You don't want a loop in your signal handler. Make `lock` a global variable, toggle it in the signal handler, check it in the `main` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some unices reset the signal handling to the defaults after the call, you have to reset it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int lock;

void f(int);

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{

  if (ac == 1) {
    printf("No argument provided");
    exit(1);
  }

  int i = atoi(av[1]);
  printf("This is argument av: %i \n", i);
  signal(SIGINT, f);
  int k = 0;
  while (k != i) {
    printf("help %d \n", k);
    while (lock == 1) {
      puts("Sleeping, waiting for signal");
      sleep(1);
    }
    sleep(1);
    k++;
  }
  return 0;
}

void f(int signum)
{
  signal(SIGINT, f);
  printf("Signal raised %d\n", signum);
  if (lock == 1) {
    lock = 0;
  } else {
    lock = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: this makes so much sense thanks for your help. I am particularly new to signal handling and spinlocks. I will make sure to reset the signal handling before quitting the program.

Comment: If you use [`sigaction`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) instead of the woefully underspecified `signal`, you can control whether signal handlers are one-shot.  It is not necessary to reset signal handlers before exiting the program; they go away when the program does, regardless.

Comment: @zwol `sigaction` is not for beginners. If they go along they will quite quickly find the limits of `signal` and pull out their can-opener to free the worms of the big tin labeled "signal handling". Most of them give up. That's called "survival of the fittest". Yes, the description of myself in my profile is utterly correct.

Comment: I don't agree; I think only `sigaction` should be taught, even to rank beginners.  Basic usage isn't that much more complicated than `signal`, it frees you from a pile of portability traps, and the more sophisticated uses are all incremental changes from the basic, instead of having to start over with a different primitive.  (And it doesn't exist on Windows, which teaches the valuable lesson that signals are not to be used on Windows.)

Comment: @zwol as much as I concur but `signal` was used for purely technical reasons :  `signal(2)` is `c89` and `POSIX.1-2001` and `sigaction(2)` is `POSIX.1-2001` and `SVr4`. Tagged was `c` and `signals` not anything with `posix` and the question was about why `signal(2)` does not work in the OP's code. It is sometimes a bit difficult to decide if you should take the question verbatim or if the actual problem is a completely different one and a direct answer to the question would lead the OP into a  *cul de sac*